# What is an appropriate backup strategy for LXD with BTRFS storage backends

Tags: backup, lxc, btrfs, lxd

I'm about to re-configure my home server from scratch and am wondering what would be the best strategy to backup my LXD containers. Meanwhile I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and have some services configured to run as LXD/LXC containers. For example:

- container "cloudserv" running seafile
- container "webservice" running nginx and MariaDB

These two containers are located on my SSD with btrfs filesystem. For data storage I am using an array of disks (also with BTRFS), where I have created another LXC storage pool with a storage volume which is the attached to the seafile container to hold all the data. The layout is something like this:

**SSD**

- BTRFS Filsystem

  - Storage Pool "Default"

    - container "cloudserv"
    - container "webservice"
    - images

**HDDs**

- BTRFS Filesystem

  - Storage Pool "DataPool1"

    - custom storage volume "seafile-data" --> attached to container "cloudserv"

By using BTRFS I was hoping to be able to make use of BTRFS snapshots and send and receive tools to easily transfer containers and storage volumes as subvolumes e.g. to a RasPi with a BTRFS volume attached.
But reading e.g. [LXD Manual](https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backup/) or [How to backup and restore LXD containers](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-backup-and-restore-lxd-containers/) I have the impression that I always have to create a tarball to backup an instance which can then be transferred. This would imply that I actually loose some of BTRFS attractive features like being able to send/receive the subvolumes/snapshots and doing incremental backups of my LXC instances and data.

Do I miss anything? Can anybody give some hints for appropriate backup workflow for LXD/LXC with BTRFS?

Answer (score 1):

If you install LXD in your remote server and both servers use Btrfs, you can use the [Optimized instance transfer](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/storage#optimized-instance-transfer) like this:

```
lxc remote add mybtrfsremotebackupserver XXX
lxc snapshot mycontainer snap1
lxc copy mycontainer mybtrfsremotebackupserver: --verbose
```

And it will use `btrf-send` for the initial transfer of the container and all its snapshots.

Then you have a very convenient way of maintaining then container and it's snapshots only sending incremental changes using the option [`--refresh` (LXD 3.7)](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/news/#container-refresh)

```
lxc copy --refresh mycontainer mybtrfsremotebackupserver: --verbose
```

But unfortunately it uses `rsync`, at least in LXD 4.0, so you will lose the `btrfs-send` optimization.

Check this issue for more info: [Feature request: --snapshots-only flag for copy](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/7902)

Also, there is ["Refresh support for custom volume copies"](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/news/#refresh-support-for-custom-volume-copies) but I'm not sure if it uses the optimized path or if it could be useful for your objective.
You can also check --optimized-storage in the lxc export

Regards